# ¿Como buscar dentro de JSON de FireBase para login?

Tags: xamarin

Tengo el siguiente código para conectarme a firebase y obtener el listado de usuarios:

```
  public  List<Usuario> usuarioData = new List<Usuario>();
  public async Task<List<Usuario>> MostrarUsuario()
  {
      var usuario = await ConexionFirebase.firebase.Child("Users").OnceAsync<Usuario>(); 
      foreach(var user in usuario)
      {
          Usuario mvUsuarios = new Usuario();
          mvUsuarios.loginpass = user.Object.loginpass;
          mvUsuarios.loginnombre = user.Object.loginnombre;
          mvUsuarios.token = user.Object.token;
          mvUsuarios.Activo = user.Object.Activo;
          mvUsuarios.IdTarea = user.Object.IdTarea;
          usuarioData.Add(mvUsuarios);
      }
      return usuarioData;
  }
```

Necesito filtrar los usuarios para encontrar si existe el usuario y comprobar si la contraseña es correcta.

Pero luego necesito actualizar el token de usuario con el del dispositivo: como obtengo el id que genera automáticamente firebase para actualizar el token del registro con ese id alfanumérico?